# The Best Way to Choose Spaces for Infection

Tags: puzzle

Consider a **5x7** patch of **1x1** square units. I can choose any 3 of the units in the patch to be infected. After 1 day, an infected square will spread to all the squares adjacent to it (no diagonal spread). My question is: "What 3 squares should i pick such that the entire **5x7** patch is infected in the fastest time possible?" (you can answer in coordinates or as a matrix of **x**'s and **o**'s) Can I also have the proof as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the patch is a grid from $(1,1)$ to $(5,7)$. Infecting $(3,1),(3,4),(3,7)$ initially ensures that all cells are infected after $3$ days.

To see why a $2$-day solution cannot exist, note that two cells separated by a [giraffe or $(4,1)$ leap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe_(chess))
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\circ&\circ&\circ&\circ&B\\
A&\circ&\circ&\circ&\circ\end{array}$$
cannot both be infected by one initial infection after $2$ days. Now consider the points $S=\{(1,1),(5,2),(1,6),(5,7)\}$, which are all at least a giraffe leap apart. Any single initial infection can infect at most one cell in $S$ after $2$ days, but there are $4$ cells in $S$ and only $3$ initial infections, so $S$ cannot be completely infected after $2$ days.